# Mocks broken after updating to Jest 26

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, create-react-app, es6-modules

I just updated react-scripts to 4.0 which includes Jest@26 and some accompanying test packages here's the package.json diff:

[image: Package diff]

After upgrading, some Jest mocks have begun to fail. It seems like the mocked return value is just undefined? Am I missing something? Here's one of the failing mocks

```
import useFetch from "use-http";

jest.mock("use-http", () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn()
}));

describe("the user context", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        useFetch.mockReturnValue({
            get: async () => Promise.resolve({ foo: 666 }),
            response: { ok: true }
        });
    });
```

Tests that try to utilize the 'get' method fail with:

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'get' of '(0 , _useHttp.default)(...)' as it is undefined.`

And another that isn't default, doesn't import the package for one-time mocks:

```
jest.mock("_hooks", () => ({
    useBaseUrls: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        app: "bar"
    })
}));
```

Tests that access the 'app' property throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined`

Comment: *It seems like the mocked return value is just undefined? Am I missing something?* - yes, it's undefined, because `jest.fn()` doesn't return anything. It's not workable regardless of Jest 26, did you try to fix this? *Tests that access the 'app' property throw* - please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: These tests were functional prior to upgrading -- for the first example note the mocked return value of `jest.fn()` before each test. For the second, a return value is defined explicitly inline. Neither test expects `jest.fn()` to return anything, just to enable mocking.

Comment: Double check that you don't have resetMocks config option or jest.resetAllMocks anywhere, initial mocks are naturally incompatible with them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jest 26 changed the default behavior of `resetMocks` to true, which resets mock state before each test.

You can revert to the prior behavior by disabling `resetMocks` in  `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  }
```

A discussion to change the default back again is currently an open issue on their Github: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9935

Comment: Thank you, I had been struggling with this for an entire morning

Comment: I had this set in `jest.config.js` and it wasn't working, adding it to package.json solved it